# How to show all the week days in SSRS Report 2014?

Tags: reporting-services

I want to show all the weekdays in my Bar chart how can i display? my query not return all the weekdays I want to show always all the weekdays on my report how can I do this?

Comment: If your dataset doesn't include all weekdays there is no way to generate values in a bar chart from SSRS expressions. I'd left join a table with all days with your current dataset to get all days even if there is no data in some days.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a table that has all the week days then join your query to it : like

```
select * into #w from (
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,0,getdate() )) weedday union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,1,getdate() )) weedday union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,2,getdate() )) weedday union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,3,getdate() )) weedday union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,4,getdate() )) weedday union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,5,getdate() )) weedday union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,6,getdate() )) weedday  ) x



select * into #d from (
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,4,getdate() )) weedday,15 amt union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,4,getdate() )) weedday,50 amt  union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,4,getdate() )) weedday,19 amt  union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,5,getdate() )) weedday,15 amt  union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,5,getdate() )) weedday,30 amt  union 
select DATENAME(dw, dateadd(dd,5,getdate() )) weedday  ,40 amt ) x


select w.weedday,d.amt
from #w w
left join #d d
on w.weedday = d.weedday
```